# Some "disappeared" dm-? files under the /dev directory

Tags: device-tree, device-mapper

Recently I took over a few RHEL systems running with the native DM-multipath, which had been installed & configured by other persons.
My doubts focus on the following questions:
1). Why there would only a part of dm-? files from dm10~19 under the /dev directory ?
2). Why all the mapper files do not point to their corresponding dm-? files which should be symbol link ?
Note: but all the complete dm-? in the system kernel can still be seen from the /proc/partitions.
Despite these symptoms, all the systems running with the native DM-multipath can do work fine.

```
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root  10, 60 Jun 22  2021 control
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  9 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvswap
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 10 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e1dc40b45101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 17 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e1bdaa115201000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 13 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e1bc43b45101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 16 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e189aa115201000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 12 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e16641b45101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 15 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e15bceba5101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 14 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e13bceba5101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 11 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001582e11141b45101000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 18 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001581c1ca81625501000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 19 Jun 22  2021 3600c0ff0001581c1895b895901000000
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 20 Jun 22  2021 vgoms-lvoms
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 21 Jun 22  2021 vghes-lvhes
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 22 Jun 22  2021 vgdata-lvoadata
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 24 Jun 22  2021 vgdata-lvhnweb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 23 Jun 22  2021 vgdata-lvdocdata
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  0 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvroot
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  1 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvhome
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  2 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvvar
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  3 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvtmp
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  4 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvinstall
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  5 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvusr
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  6 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvopenv
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  7 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvapp
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  8 Jun 22  2021 vgroot-Lvoracle
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 25 Nov 23 17:24 vgqdisk-lvqdisk
# 
# 
# 
# ls -l /dev/dm-*
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 10 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-10
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 11 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-11
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 12 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-12
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 13 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-13
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 14 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-14
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 15 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-15
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 16 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-16
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 17 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-17
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 18 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-18
brw-rw---- 1 root root 253, 19 Jun 22  2021 /dev/dm-19
# 
# 
# 
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 104     0  292935982 cciss/c0d0
 104     1     104391 cciss/c0d0p1
 104     2  292824787 cciss/c0d0p2
   8     0     976512 sda
   8    16   97656192 sdb
   8    32   97656192 sdc
   8    48   97656192 sdd
   8    64   97656192 sde
   8    80   97656192 sdf
   8    96   97656192 sdg
   8   112   97656192 sdh
   8   128  585937472 sdi
   8   144  989858240 sdj
   8   160     976512 sdk
   8   176   97656192 sdl
   8   192   97656192 sdm
   8   208   97656192 sdn
   8   224   97656192 sdo
   8   240   97656192 sdp
  65     0   97656192 sdq
  65    16   97656192 sdr
  65    32  585937472 sds
  65    48  989858240 sdt
 253     0   10485760 dm-0
 253     1    5242880 dm-1
 253     2    5242880 dm-2
 253     3    5242880 dm-3
 253     4   15728640 dm-4
 253     5   10485760 dm-5
 253     6   20971520 dm-6
 253     7   20971520 dm-7
 253     8   62914560 dm-8
 253     9   16777216 dm-9
 253    10     976512 dm-10
 253    11   97656192 dm-11
 253    12   97656192 dm-12
 253    13   97656192 dm-13
 253    14   97656192 dm-14
 253    15   97656192 dm-15
 253    16   97656192 dm-16
 253    17   97656192 dm-17
 253    18  585937472 dm-18
 253    19  989858240 dm-19
 253    20  989855744 dm-20
 253    21  585105408 dm-21
 253    22  209715200 dm-22
 253    23  209715200 dm-23
 253    24  209715200 dm-24
 253    25     974848 dm-25
# 
# 



# 
# 
# multipath -ll
3600c0ff0001581c1ca81625501000000 dm-18 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=559G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:9  sds        65:32 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:9  sdi        8:128 [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e13bceba5101000000 dm-14 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:5  sdo        8:224 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:5  sde        8:64  [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e15bceba5101000000 dm-15 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:6  sdp        8:240 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:6  sdf        8:80  [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e1bc43b45101000000 dm-13 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:3  sdn        8:208 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:3  sdd        8:48  [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e1dc40b45101000000 dm-10 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=954M][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:0  sdk        8:160 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:0  sda        8:0   [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e11141b45101000000 dm-11 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:1  sdl        8:176 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:1  sdb        8:16  [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e16641b45101000000 dm-12 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:2  sdm        8:192 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:2  sdc        8:32  [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001581c1895b895901000000 dm-19 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=944G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:10 sdt        65:48 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:10 sdj        8:144 [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e1bdaa115201000000 dm-17 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:8  sdr        65:16 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:8  sdh        8:112 [active][ready]
3600c0ff0001582e189aa115201000000 dm-16 HP,P2000 G3 FC
[size=93G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=50][active]
 \_ 2:0:2:7  sdq        65:0  [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=10][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:3:7  sdg        8:96  [active][ready]
#
#
# rpm -Vav|grep /etc/udev/rules.d
........    /etc/udev/rules.d
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/05-udev-early.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/51-hotplug.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/90-dm.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/95-pam-console.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/61-uinput-stddev.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/61-uinput-wacom.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/90-hal.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/90-ib.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/90-alsa.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/60-raw.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/xen-backend.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/40-multipath.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/60-net.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/90-hal.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/60-wacom.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/98-kexec.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/85-pcscd_ccid.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/51-dlm.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules
........  c /etc/udev/rules.d/bluetooth.rules
........    /etc/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
# 
# 
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/90-dm*
KERNEL=="dm-[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"
# 
#
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the current multipath configuration details? `multipath -ll`

Comment: Note the major&minor device numbers of the `/dev/mapper/vg*` files: it looks like the missing `/dev/dm-[0-9]` devices would correspond to LVs of the `vgroot` volume group. Also, which version of RHEL is this? And is there Oracle ASM in use? ASM requires that each disk that is managed by it must have exactly one device visible to it, and the elimination of the usual symbolic links might have been the previous admin's idea for implementing that.

Comment: These are all the RHEL 5.8 systems.

Comment: Yes, all the "disappeared" dm-? files correspond the LVs within the vgroot,  and also there is no ASM disk in use！

Comment: @telcoM  thus,  what ever the purpose or benefit about this implementation would be ?

Comment: With ASM, there is (or used to be) a requirement that any disk that might come under ASM management is presented once and only once. If there are things like multipathing or software RAID, the component devices should be hidden from ASM and only the "aggregate" device presented to it. I could imagine someone not realizing that they can adjust the ASM_DISKSTRING parameter and create dedicated device aliases for ASM use, and trying to eliminate duplicates by removing `/dev/dm-*` devices and the like. But since there is no ASM, that theory went into the trash already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know the answer to your question 1.)
But I notice that all the missing `/dev/dm-*` devices nodes are related to LVM device mappings.

But for question 2.)
In RHEL 5.x, the practice of using symbolic links in the `/dev/mapper` directory was not yet implemented. The old version of `udev` used in that release was more permissive than the modern `systemd`-integrated version.

Having real device nodes as both `/dev/mapper/vg*` files and as corresponding `/dev/dm-*` files (instead of `/dev/mapper/vg*` being symlinks to corresponding `/dev/dm-*`) was normal for that release.

The same might be true for dm-multipath, although I cannot confirm that since my only remaining RHEL 5.x test VM is not configured for multipaths.

I also note that the timestamp on most of the `/dev/mapper/*` and `/dev/dm-*` device nodes suggests this system has been running continuously for about 1.5 years now. But `/dev/mapper/vgqdisk-lvqdisk` is dated Nov 23 so some parts of the storage configuration has been changed fairly recently, and its corresponding `/dev/dm-25` is also missing.

Have you checked for custom udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`? Note that RHEL 5.x had *all* its udev rules there; the separation to distribution's standard rules in `/usr/lib/udev/` and sysadmin's customizations in `/etc/udev/` did not exist yet in RHEL 5.x. If the previous administrator had written comments for their (possible) custom rules, those comments might explain what they had been thinking.

To find out if non-default rules exist, you'll need to run this command:

```
sudo rpm -Vav | grep /etc/udev/rules.d
```

This will output a list of udev rule files known to the RPM package management: if a file is unchanged from what the respective RPM package contained, the filename will be prefixed with 8 dots: `........`.

Then you'll need to compare this list of files to the files actually in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory: if there are any files that were not listed by the `rpm` command, they would be customizations added by the previous sysadmin and should be inspected to see if they might be causing the missing device nodes.

And of course, there is the possibility that the `/dev/dm-*` devices went missing because of some mistyped command, and if the system is rebooted, it will recreate all the `/dev/dm-*` devices as normal. If you run `sudo lsof +aL1 /dev` and find the missing devices in a still-open state, that might support the theory that the deletion was a random sysadmin "oops".

(When taking over old systems that have been running continuously for a long time, it might be a good idea to ask for the old administrator to demonstrate that the system can in fact be rebooted without errors, before the new admin accepts responsibility for it. That way, there is a good chance for any hidden issues to become visible, and all sorts of blame games can be avoided. But I understand it is not always practically possible to arrange for such a test...)

Comment: Still not sure why just only the dm-? files corresponding to the LVs within the vgroot were missing？
Note: I had confirmed it with the lsof +aL1 that you recommended, there is no any missing dm-? file.

Comment: @tecoM  It at least has nothing to do with the personal misoperation that manually deleting the dm-? files. 
BTW,  I had contacted with the previous administrator, and also confirmed not doing those deletions.

Comment: So it's not intentional, and not a mistake *that they had noticed*. It might still be a result of an *unnoticed* mistake... but try `sudo rpm -Vav | grep /etc/udev/rules.d` to see if any standard udev rules have been customized: if all displayed lines start with 8 dots `........`, then the standard rules are all unchanged. Then run `rpm -qla | grep /etc/udev/rules.d` and compare to the actual contents of the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory to see if any custom rule files have been added. Changes or additions might be related.

Comment: @tecoM   I think that I have found the answer  of the Q1 via your guidance.   The missing dm-? files were just "shielded" by the /etc/udev/rules.d/90-dm.rules.